# Recycling the CD boot image for an USB drive

Tags: boot, bootloader, boot-partition

Is it possible to use a CD boot image (the bin  file) as a bootsector for a partition of an UFD drive?
Can I use `dd` for this task?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is your end goal? There are plenty of ways to [make a bootable flash drive](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootable+flash+drive+linux).

Comment: These tools, as far as I know, take a whole ISO and transfer it onto a UFD. I just want to use some boot image that I have to create a different disk, not a replica of the ISO. The first time I could use your GUI applets to transfer the ISO on the UFD and then change/delete the files at my wish. But thereafter, if I need to test another boot image, I need to backup UFD, format it, transfer ISO, delete ISO files and restore backup. Very time consuming. This is why I need a method to transfer only bootsector images.